# powershell, dynamically create a modifiable enum at run time

Tags: powershell

I want to dynamically create a modifiable `enum` at runtime from data stored in a `[string[]]`

at first I used

```
$fruits = 'apple','orange'
Add-Type "public enum fruits { $($fruits -join ",`n") }"
```

but when on the second run the fruits list change I get the `add-type : Cannot add type. The type name 'fruits' already exists.` error

I then tried

```
$fruits = 'apple','orange'
[scriptblock]::create("enum fruits {$($fruits -join "`n")}").invoke()
```

but the script is executed in its own context and the newly created `enum` is not visible

I then found this way to *dot-source* a `scriptblock`

```
$fruits = 'apple','orange'
$executioncontext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($false, [scriptblock]::create("enum fruits {$($fruits -join "`n")}"), $null, $null)
```

now I can dynamically redefine my `enum` at will without any error. eg,

```
$fruits = 'apple','orange','banana'
$executioncontext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($false, [scriptblock]::create("enum fruits {$($fruits -join "`n")}"), $null, $null)
```

this works very well but seems to me a bit complicated. did I miss something? is there a simpler way to dynamically create a modifiable `enum` in Powershell 5.1?

### context

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.4046
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.4046
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops... the answer was obvious

```
$fruits = 'apple','orange','peach'
$CreateEnum = [scriptblock]::create("enum fruits {$($fruits -join "`n")}")
. $CreateEnum
```

or even simpler,

```
$fruits = 'apple','orange','peach'
. ([scriptblock]::create("enum fruits {$($fruits -join "`n")}"))
```

Comment: Nice; while `Invoke-Expression` is generally to be avoided, here it is appropriate and simplifies things a bit: `Invoke-Expression "enum fruits {$($fruits -join "`n")}"`

Comment: @mklement0 any link explaining why `Invoke-Expression` is to be avoided? I'm curious

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)'s my summary, which also links to the documentation.